# How can I import scipy.stats without a 'DLL load failed' error?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

using python in the command prompt i can import scipy, but when tryin to import scipy.stats i get the following output:

> > > import scipy
> > >
> > > import scipy.stats

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats__init__.py", line 384, in 
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in 
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\spatial__init__.py", line 102, in 
    from ._procrustes import procrustes
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\spatial_procrustes.py", line 11, in 
    from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg__init__.py", line 195, in 
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in 
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215, in 
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have searched for similar problems in stack overflow but can't seem to find the fix. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you provide some information on your environment? How did you install the library, for example?

Comment: pip install numpy

Comment: pip install scipy

Comment: Try `pip3 install scipy` and `pip3 install numpy` as well as the `pip3.7` variants.

Comment: @David Which versions did you end up with? Are you using virtual environments, or similar tools?